# Flutter build apk Failed

Tags: firebase, flutter, kotlin

I'm trying to build a new android apk from the flutter project, the minSdkVersion was 19 and the apk generated successfully, but not work on all android devices, some devices work with minSdkVersion 16, so when I changed the mindsVersion to 16 I cannot generate it cause I still get an error  `uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [com.google.firebase:firebase-core:20.0.0]`

I'm trying to downgrade the Firebase Core but I cannot and still get this output.

here's my app/build.gradle

```
....
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.2')
}
```

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

and here's my android/gradle

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

}
```

}

can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

For me using minSdkVersion 26 is the sweet spot.

```
defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.app"
            minSdkVersion 26
            targetSdkVersion 30
            versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
            versionName flutterVersionName
            multiDexEnabled true
}
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
}
```

**android/gradle**

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.0'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.0'
}
```

Comment: If you want to support more Android devices, you can set SDK minimum at 21 level. Android 28 it is Android 8, and on [this](https://www.statista.com/statistics/921152/mobile-android-version-share-worldwide/) link you can see that Android 5-7 (SDK level 21 it is Android 5) is still in use.

Answer (score 0):

You should downgrade flutter [firebase_core](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core/changelog) too.